# Increase sound tempo in Unity when new player joins in Kinect game

Tags: unity, c#, sound, kinect

I'm using Unity to create a Windows-build game with Kinect.

I have some drum beats, which can either be used as single sound effect or be edited to be a piece of continuous music. I want these drum beats to be the background sound of my game.

I want the drum beats to go at a constant pace, but when new users join, the beats go faster without changing its pitch.

Can I achieve this Unity with either plugin or code? Or do I need to use stuff like Max/MSP to run with Unity at the same time?

Comment: What have you tried so far using your research of Unity's audio components? Where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: if you are playing beats on a specific frequency you just need to reduce it, if you have a track of beats you need to speed up you can, but it will change the pitch.